# Ubuntu 12.04 PHP 5.3 to 5.5 update fails

Tags: php5, apt

on a Ubuntu 12.04 Server I´m trying to update PHP 5.3 to 5.5 this is what I have done:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php5
```

unfortuntely the installation ends with following error:

```
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/apache2-bin_2.4.16-4+deb.sury.org~precise+4_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/man/man8/apache2.8.gz', which is also in package apache2.2-common 2.2.22-1ubuntu1.10
dpkg-deb (subprocess): subprocess data was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess <decompress> returned error exit status 2
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/apache2-bin_2.4.16-4+deb.sury.org~precise+4_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

It seems PHP 5 affects Apache 2.2 as well. Thankful for help why the subprocess was killed.

**EDIT:** I solved this by uninstalling apache2.2 completely and reinstalling 2.4 which worked without errors.

Comment: Run `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` and try again.

Comment: As this is a production server only security upgrades are run. If I run `dist-upgrade` I´m worried packages like postgresql are update blindly which breaks something. any other chance than that?

Comment: Why on earth are you doing anything this disruptive on a production server without testing it first?

Comment: Sorry I was unclear here. This is a staging VM with a snapshot **this will be repeated on production**. so everything save here. But anyway the issue with dist-upgrade is the same.

Answer (score 1):

I got same problem when upgrade PHP, you can try this

`sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite  /var/cache/apt/archives/apache2-bin_2.4.16-4+deb.sury.org~precise+4_amd64.deb`

and then install php5 by

`sudo apt-get -f install php5`

this will upgrade apache2, enjoy it.